# File not found Exception.. But it's there

Tags: c#, file, .net

Hey this is going to be one of those dumb questions. I am trying to pick up a file on my local system and I keep getting a `FileNotFoundException` thrown.

Someone set me straight please :)

```
if( File.Exists(@"C:\logs\hw-healthways-prod_2009-08-26.tar"))
{
     Console.WriteLine("Yay");
}
else
{
     throw new FileNotFoundException();   
}
```

Tried moving the file into the same location as the executing application and did the following:

```
 if( File.Exists("hw-healthways-prod_2009-08-26.tar"))
```

Same thing.

Then I made a random txt file and parked it there too.. "me.txt"

And it works?! So you thing the file name is the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try doing `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\logs")`.  It's possible that the file in question has odd characters that are getting interpreted one way by Windows Explorer (presumably where you're reading "the file's property" from?) but a different way by the .NET Framework.  This can happen if you have UTF-8 characters in the filename (perhaps an en dash?).

Answer (score 16):

May be the name of the file is "hw-healthways-prod_2009-08-26**.tar.tar**" instead of "hw-healthways-prod_2009-08-26**.tar**", I had this problem because by default the extension files are hidden on windows

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your file permissions. Your computer may not have permission to the file.

Answer (score -6):

C:\logs\hw-healthways-prod_2009-08-26.tar should be C:\\logs\\hw-healthways-prod_2009-08-26.tar. \ means the next character is an escape character.

Comment: Not when the string is prefixed with the @ character.