# file not found for a jar file -- even when I get the file name via Directory.getFiles()

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net

I am trying to run a jar file with a shell command but am getting a file not found exception. I found this post which says to use `Directory.getFiles`: [File not found Exception.. But it's there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350076/file-not-found-exception-but-its-there)

When I follow the advice in that post I get some really wierd behavior:

```
Dim files As List(Of String) = Directory.GetFiles("Path\Java").ToList //returns one file
Shell(files.First) //throws file not found exception
```

I am able to run this jar w/ the command line in windows via `path\java\java -jar myDriver.jar argumentOne`

What's going on? How can I run this jar file from within .NET code?

Comment: Could be a permissions issue.

Comment: @leppie so I would have permissions to read the contents of the directory but not execute?

Comment: Relative path problem probably. Is path/java in the same path as your bin/exe ?

Comment: No, sorry, GetFiles would throw an exception. I was thinking of `File.Exists`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe the fact that your shell command does not match the run command.

```
Shell(PathToFile)
```

Is not the same as:

```
Shell(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", "C:\PATHTOJAVA",PathToFile,Argument)
```